# query to list only latest record of users

Tags: php, sql, sql-server, sqlsrv

I have a database with 2 set of table which is Users and Record.so i want to list out latest record for each user in certain group but what happen is the result display the latest and the first record for user that i just update record which is '27/4/300' and '4/5/2108'.The date attribute which is 'tarikh' is in Record table,while users_id is in Users table.Do someone know better query to get the result that i want?

```
$sql =   "SELECT * from Users, Record 
          WHERE Users.users_id = Record.users_id
          AND Users.group_id='$users_group'
          AND Record.tarikh IN (SELECT max(Record.tarikh) FROM Record
          GROUP BY users_id)";
```

[image: click here ,this is picture of result of the query]

I am using sql server management studio 17

Comment: The use of `select *` with `group by` suggests that this query would generate a syntax error in sQL Server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.

```
$sql =   "SELECT * from Users, Record 
          WHERE Users.users_id = Record.users_id
          AND Users.group_id='$users_group'
          AND Record.tarikh = (SELECT max(Record_nested.tarikh) FROM Record as Record_nested 
                                where Record_nested.users_id = Record.users_id)";
```